# Anuglar5 HttpClient Get - how to convert response into a number

Tags: angular, httpclient, observable

I'm trying to implement real time cpu usage chart, however i have trouble figuring out how to squeeze the value itself from the Observable.

My get call returns a single number.
Ideally I want to call the getData function straight from the addPoint method.

Is it even possible? What am i getting wrong?

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.addPoint();
}

addPoint() {
    this.interval = setTimeout(() => {
        this.chart.addPoint(this.getData(), 0, true, this.chart.ref.series[0].data.length > 10);            
    }, 1000);
}

getData() {
    return this.http.get<Number>('http://localhost:5000/cpu_usage');        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not subscribe to your http request and add the point after you receive the data.

```
addPoint() {
    this.getData().subscribe(point => {
        this.chart.addPoint(point, 0, true, this.chart.ref.series[0].data.length > 10)
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I got stuck and did not even think i could do this the other way around.